# Simple SQL Server query across databases runs extremely slow R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql

I have two databases on a local machine, connected to `localhost`.  They both have roughly two million rows a piece.  I was doing the following very simple join and it took over a minute to complete.

```
select distinct x.patid
    from [i 3 sci study].dbo.clm_extract as x
    left join [i 3 study].dbo.claims as y on y.patid=x.patid
    where y.patid is null
```

When I looked at the execution plan I saw that the join showplan operator had this to say
[image]

Why is the actual number of rows so exorbitantly high compared to the actual number of rows in both tables?

Comment: How many rows are actually in each table? Does either table have an index on patid?

Comment: right at 2 million a per table.  i didn't include an index on patid because the SQL Server-suggested missing index included something like five fields

Comment: So there's no index and you're wondering why your query trying to match 2 million rows on one side to 2 million rows on the other side is slow? What is wrong with an index having more than one column? And do you mean the index had five columns, or literally used INCLUDE to bring along five extra columns?

Comment: nothing is wrong with more than one column in an index.  it suggested INCLUDE to bring along five extra columns.  I know with no index it'd take a little while, but i'm not well-versed with the execution plan nomenclature and i couldn't think of a way to get 76 millions rows for that join operator to churn through.

Comment: It's actually 761 million rows. And the estimates are far worse. There is a much better model for your query (try NOT EXISTS), but if your main concern is optimizing THIS query, I would consider an index on just the patid columns on both sides (forget about the INLCUDE nonsense that you got from Management Studio's garbage index recommendations).

Comment: my question wasn't so much this query in particular as i thought maybe the two tables being in a different database made it more work on sql server and how the 761 million rows came about. but now that i think about it, i may have figured that out

Comment: where not exists took execution time down from 65 seconds to one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `LEFT JOIN` will match each row on the left with each row on the right, and then filter. Assuming `patid` is not unique in either table, the number of possible match combinations could get very high.

Try the following:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
GO
CREATE TABLE #t1 (Id INT NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE #t2 (Id INT NOT NULL);
GO

INSERT #t1 (Id)
VALUES (1);
GO 100

INSERT #t2 (Id)
SELECT Id FROM #t1;
GO
```

Now look at the execution plan for the left join query form:

```
SELECT *
FROM #t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN #t2 ON #t1.Id = #t2.Id
WHERE #t2.Id IS NULL;
```

Looking at the execution plan, the hash join shows 10,000 actual rows (100 from #t1 x 100 from #t2). This shows the advantage of checking for existence (or a lack thereof) using any of the following T-SQL syntaxes:

```
SELECT #t1.Id
FROM #t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #t2 WHERE Id = #t1.Id);

-- #t2.Id must not contain any NULLs for this to be correct
SELECT #t1.Id
FROM #t1
WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT #t2.Id FROM #t2);

-- Returns DISTINCT #t1 values
SELECT Id
FROM #t1
EXCEPT
SELECT Id 
FROM #t2;
```

Checking for a lack of existence enables the engine to short circuit. This is due to the anti semi join. As soon as the first match is found, it moves on to the next record. For more details, [see this blog post](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/).