# Improve query performance when joining on a linked server table

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

Unfortunately as a temporary measure whilst we fix our datacentre I need to run the following cross server query, can anyone suggest how I can get the performance to increase...

as have to run this statement at the start of a cursor

```
SELECT t.SearchId, t.VisitSourceId, t.SiteDomainId, t.trpUTMid, t.FlightPlus, t.StartDate,
t.CountryId, t.ProvinceId, t.Locationid, t.PlaceId, t.EstabId, t.CheckInDate, 
t.CheckOutDate, t.Rooms, t.Room1Adults, t.Room1Children, t.Room2Adults, t.Room2Children, 
t.Room3Adults, t.Room3Children, tc.OutcomeDate, tc.OutcomeId, tc.HotelsFound, tc.Notes

FROM [MLT_VisitTracking].[dbo].TrackingAcomSearches_tbl t
INNER JOIN TrackingAcomSearchesOutcome_tbl tc
ON t.trpUTMid = tc.trpUTMid
LEFT JOIN [YAZOO].[MLT_VisitTracking].[dbo].TrackingAcomSearches_tbl tid
ON t.trpUTMid = tid.trpUTMid
WHERE tid.trpUTMid IS NULL
```

Comment: There are several questions on this site about improving linked server query performance, did they help? And what specific information can you give about the tables (rowcount, expected rowcount in the query) and the current execution plan? The bottom line is that linked servers are always slow; do you have the option of moving data from one server to the other, then running the query?

Comment: can try using Openquery, also if you can change your query to be an inner join you can use the remote hint: (inner REMOTE join)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible option would be to get the remote table replicated to the local server. This would put all tables on the same server, enabling the optimizer to use statistics to generate the best plan. Since you are only using trpUTMid, you could just replicate that column.

Another option would be to use temp tables. Same idea, get all tables on the same server:

```
SELECT trpUTMid
INTO #Yazoo_TrackingAcomSearches_tbl
FROM [YAZOO].[MLT_VisitTracking].[dbo].TrackingAcomSearches_tbl


SELECT t.SearchId, t.VisitSourceId, t.SiteDomainId, t.trpUTMid, t.FlightPlus, t.StartDate,
t.CountryId, t.ProvinceId, t.Locationid, t.PlaceId, t.EstabId, t.CheckInDate, 
t.CheckOutDate, t.Rooms, t.Room1Adults, t.Room1Children, t.Room2Adults, t.Room2Children, 
t.Room3Adults, t.Room3Children, tc.OutcomeDate, tc.OutcomeId, tc.HotelsFound, tc.Notes

FROM [MLT_VisitTracking].[dbo].TrackingAcomSearches_tbl t
INNER JOIN TrackingAcomSearchesOutcome_tbl tc
ON t.trpUTMid = tc.trpUTMid
LEFT JOIN #Yazoo_TrackingAcomSearches_tbl tid
ON t.trpUTMid = tid.trpUTMid
WHERE tid.trpUTMid IS NULL
```

You could also create an index on the temp table to improve performance.

I'd also recommend checking for lack of existence rather than the old left join where null ( read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13140520/simple-sql-server-query-across-databases-runs-extremely-slow-r2/13144369#13144369) for more info ):

```
SELECT trpUTMid
INTO #Yazoo_TrackingAcomSearches_tbl
FROM [YAZOO].[MLT_VisitTracking].[dbo].TrackingAcomSearches_tbl


SELECT t.SearchId, t.VisitSourceId, t.SiteDomainId, t.trpUTMid, t.FlightPlus, t.StartDate,
t.CountryId, t.ProvinceId, t.Locationid, t.PlaceId, t.EstabId, t.CheckInDate, 
t.CheckOutDate, t.Rooms, t.Room1Adults, t.Room1Children, t.Room2Adults, t.Room2Children, 
t.Room3Adults, t.Room3Children, tc.OutcomeDate, tc.OutcomeId, tc.HotelsFound, tc.Notes

FROM [MLT_VisitTracking].[dbo].TrackingAcomSearches_tbl t
INNER JOIN TrackingAcomSearchesOutcome_tbl tc
ON t.trpUTMid = tc.trpUTMid
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT NULL 
    FROM #Yazoo_TrackingAcomSearches_tbl
    WHERE trpUTMid = t.trpUTMid
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below query

```
;with cte
    as(
    SELECT tc.OutcomeDate, tc.OutcomeId, tc.HotelsFound, tc.Notes
    GROUP BY [BatchId]  FROM TrackingAcomSearchesOutcome_tbl tc
    )
     SELECT t.SearchId, t.VisitSourceId, t.SiteDomainId, t.trpUTMid, t.FlightPlus, t.StartDate,
    t.CountryId, t.ProvinceId, t.Locationid, t.PlaceId, t.EstabId, t.CheckInDate, 
    t.CheckOutDate, t.Rooms, t.Room1Adults, t.Room1Children, t.Room2Adults, t.Room2Children, 
    t.Room3Adults, t.Room3Children

    FROM [MLT_VisitTracking].[dbo].TrackingAcomSearches_tbl t
    INNER JOIN cte as tbl ON t.trpUTMid = tbl .trpUTMid
    LEFT JOIN [YAZOO].[MLT_VisitTracking].[dbo].TrackingAcomSearches_tbl tid
    ON t.trpUTMid = tbl .trpUTMid
    WHERE tid.trpUTMid IS NULL
```

Comment: it doesn't compile, I have no batchid